# The interpretation of double const* const* X in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Given that X is a array of arrays, what is the interpretation of

```
double const* const* X
```

in c++?
Is it correct to say that X is a pointer to a constant pointer to a constant double?

Comment: *Is it correct to say that X is a pointer to a constant pointer to a constant double?* Yes, read from right to left.

Comment: so the values that X[i][j] are pointing to, are not mutable?

Comment: Yes, they're const-qualified.

Comment: "Given that X is an array of arrays" -- but it's not. It's a pointer to a pointer, with `const` qualifiers. Pointers and arrays are different things. Yes, the **name** of an array often decays into a pointer to its first element, so an array and a pointer often look interchangeable, but they're not. And, in particular, the name of an array of arrays does not turn into a pointer to a pointer, just into a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

From [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=double+const*+const*+X+):

> declare X as pointer to const pointer to const double

cdecl is an awesome tool for those the types of people who like to use calculators instead of doing mental maths (aka engineers, because we are lazy).